# Shortlist plugin error when creating a new list

Tags: plugin-shortlist

I'm getting this error when I try create a new list:

`` CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'userSlug' doesn't have a default value. The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `craft_shortlist_list` (`default`, `public`, `type`, `ownerType`, `uid`, `ownerId`, `id`, `dateUpdated`, `dateCreated`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3, :yp4, :yp5, :yp6, :yp7, :yp8). Bound with :yp0=0, :yp1=1, :yp2='manual', :yp3='member', :yp4='8fb7840a-a399-4eb3-bdf7-c59cb656bbff', :yp5='1', :yp6=1698, :yp7='2017-04-24 09:11:47', :yp8='2017-04-24 09:11:47' ``

Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: My guess would this this is a bug with the plugin.  Have you tried contacting the developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the 'userSlug' field in 'shortlist_list' table to allow null and it seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using an older version of the plugin.

That bug was definitely fixed in the current version - which is actually 1.0.4 - although oddly that is not available as a 'public release' it seems.

I'd contact Joel and get him to update his version page! http://squarebit.co.uk/contact